# Scheme Firestore

Tags: sql, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

How to get all comments for a user (id) if there are a billion ads in the database and

mb there should be a different base structure for comments?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SalVl.png)

My question is not what code to write, but how to correctly match comments with announcements so that you can find user comments with minimal cost

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get all ads IDs and then their sub collections:

```
const adsSnapshot = firebase.firestore().collection("ads").get()
const adIDs = adsSnapshot.docs.map(ad => firebase.firestore().collection("ads").doc(ad.id).collection("comments").get())
const commentsSnap = await Promise.all(adIDs)
```

There you get a query Snapshot of all comments from all ADS. You can parse it as per you needs.

To prevent reads for getting all ADs IDs and easy querying comments, you can create a dedicated collection of comments containing, commentID, userID, adID and the timestamp.

Comment: wouldn't it be an ineffective way if there are billions of ads ?

Comment: My question is not what code to write, but how to correctly match comments with announcements so that you can find user comments with minimal cost

Comment: @antnotttxxa then I'd rather create a separate collection for comments where each document will contain, comment ID, user ID, AD ID and timestamp when it was created. Then you can sort comments based on timestamp, user or ad.

Comment: if I have a billion ads, then I will have 50 times more comments, such a table it will not cause any problems?

Comment: @antnotttxxa first of all, Firestore is not a SQL DB with the tabular structure. It's NoSQL. Whenever you create a new document it creates an index for it. So if you have 5 ads or million, it's going to take same amount of time to query. You can watch [this](https://youtu.be/Ofux_4c94FI?t=326) for more explanation